# How to get cumulative sum of unique IDs with group by?

Tags: python, pandas, data-processing

I am very new to python and pandas working on a pandas dataframe which looks like

```
Date     Time           ID   Weight
Jul-1     12:00         A       10
Jul-1     12:00         B       20
Jul-1     12:00         C       100
Jul-1     12:10         C       100
Jul-1     12:10         D       30
Jul-1     12:20         C       100
Jul-1     12:20         D       30
Jul-1     12:30         A       10
Jul-1     12:40         E       40
Jul-1     12:50         F       50
Jul-1     1:00          A       40
```

I am trying to achieve group by date, Time and ids and apply cumulative sum such that if an id is present in the next time-slot the weight is only added once(uniquely). The resulting data frame would look like this

```
Date     Time           Weight   
Jul-1     12:00         130     (10+20+100)
Jul-1     12:10         160     (10+20+100+30)
Jul-1     12:20         160     (10+20+100+30)
Jul-1     12:30         160     (10+20+100+30)
Jul-1     12:40         200     (10+20+100+30+40)
Jul-1     12:50         250     (10+20+100+30+40+50)
Jul-1     01:00         250     (10+20+100+30+40+50)
```

This is what I tried below, however this is still counting the weights multiple times:

```
df=df.groupby(['date','time','ID'])['Wt'].apply(lambda x: x.unique().sum()).reset_index()
df['cumWt']=df['Wt'].cumsum()
```

Any help would be really appreciated!

Thanks a lot in advance!!

Comment: check groupby and agg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code below uses [pandas.duplicate()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html), [pandas.merge()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html), [pandas.groupby/sum](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html) and [pandas.cumsum()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.DataFrame.cumsum.html) to come to the desired output:

```
# creates a series of weights to be considered and rename it to merge
unique_weights = df['weight'][~df.duplicated(['weight'])]
unique_weights.rename('consider_cum', inplace = True)

# merges the series to the original dataframe and replace the ignored values by 0
df = df.merge(unique_weights.to_frame(), how = 'left', left_index=True, right_index=True)
df.consider_cum = df.consider_cum.fillna(0)

# sums grouping by date and time
df = df.groupby(['date', 'time']).sum().reset_index()

# create the cumulative sum column and present the output
df['weight_cumsum'] = df['consider_cum'].cumsum()
df[['date', 'time', 'weight_cumsum']]
```

Produces the following output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot @Daniel!